# How to resolve Javascript error '.then is not a function'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, callback

The following code is fetching csv data from S3 and converting it to JSON.
I am getting `.then is not a function` error on the following. What can be the possible issue?

```
var Papa = require('papaparse');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')

let deferred = this.$q.defer();
s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        //console.log(err, err.stack);
        deferred.reject(err);
      }
      else {
        const csv = data.Body.toString('utf-8');
        const headers = 'id,start,end,count';
        const parsed = Papa.parse(headers + '\n' + csv, parseOptions);
        var parsedData = parsed.data;
        console.log(parsedData); //this works

        deferred.resolve(parsedData);  // resolve the deferred with the data
      }
      return deferred.promise;
    }).then(function(parsedData) {
      console.log(parsedData);

    }).catch( function(err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
    });

  }
```

Comment: If you pass a callback function to `s3.getObject()` I bet it does not return a Promise. Don't mix the two styles; put the callback code into a `.then()` also.

Answer (score 0):

```
s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
   ...
   return deferred.promise;
}).then(function(parsedData) {
  ...
})
```

`s3.getObject()` appears to be a callback-style API that does NOT return a promise. Sure, it's *callback* appears to, but the `getObject()` function itself does not.

What you need to do is convert `s3.getObject()` to return a promise. Node has [`utils.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) which will take a callback-style API and return a version of that function that returns a promise. You can probably do:

```
const util = require('util')

const getObject = util.promisify(s3.getObject)

getObject(params)
  .then(function(parsedData){
    ...
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

aws-sdk.js was originally written with callbacks and later on they introduced promises.
What you simply need to do is add `.promise()` to your `getObject` and your fixed.

Here is an example:

```
s3
.getObject(params)
.promise()
.then(data => {
  const csv = data.Body.toString('utf-8');
  const headers = 'id,start,end,count';
  const parsed = Papa.parse(headers + '\n' + csv, parseOptions);
  return parsed.data
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err, err.stack);
})
```